# Visual Studio 11 Missing Assembly references

Tags: visual-studio, assembly-references, visual-studio-2012

Upon trying to build even the simplest Metro application in Visual Studio, I get a dozen or so errors regarding missing assembly references (error WMC1003). I just installed VS 11 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543

Any and all help is appreciated!
Below is the part of the output of the build which specifies the errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.Foundation'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v1.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(95,9): XamlCompiler error WMC1003: Window Runtime Reference Assembly is missing: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only build Metro apps on Windows 8. Are you using this?

If not download the Windows 8 Developer preview with VS 2011 installed.

http://dev.windows.com/

Edit: Note from download link

*In order to develop Metro style applications, the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview must be installed on the Windows Developer Preview with developer tools English, **64-bit**. Developing Metro style applications on other Preview versions of Windows 8 is not supported.*

Note2: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/toolsforwinapps/thread/12057f17-2f6c-422e-836e-47bcb1656a5d

Developing Windows Metro style Applications

At BUILD the only platform for developing Windows Metro style applications is the Windows Developer Preview with developer tools English, 64-bit (x64)  The limitation of 64bit only for Metro style development tools is only for BUILD. 32 bit versions of Visual Studio will support Metro style development in future pre-releases.

- this includes Visual Studio Express for Windows and Blend Developer
  Previews as well as installing the Windows SDKs starting Friday, you 
  will have access to Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview, install this 
  on Windows Developer Preview with developer tools English, 64-bit
- **(x64) building Metro style applications is not supported on any other
  image**

  Note: Visual Studio 11 Express for Windows Developer Preview
  will not be available for download separately

Comment: i am using win8, but the one with VS installed is too big for my CD or USB

Comment: Ok next question would be that did you download the 64 bit version of Windows 8?

Comment: Reading the note again I see not only 64 bit but must be "installed on Developer Preview with developer tools english". Which means the Metro stuff won't work.